# Change AngularJS Vivid-Vortex Directive to plain characters

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I'm working with the Recaptcha Directive (https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha) Does anybody know how to change the Captcha-Type from "Select all fruits [or hamburgers or whatever]" to the good old "Type all characters that are in the box" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call that renders g-recaptcha: https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/blob/2770706f11a1c5cfd6472275030863e0200e92c4/src/service.js#L55

```
        create: function (elm, key, fn, conf) {
            conf.callback = fn;
            conf.sitekey = key;

            return getRecaptcha().then(function (recaptcha) {
                return recaptcha.render(elm, conf);
            });
        }
```

Call that calls this create function in the directive: https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/blob/2770706f11a1c5cfd6472275030863e0200e92c4/src/directive.js#L63

```
                vcRecaptcha.create(elm[0], key, callback, {

                    theme: scope.theme || attrs.theme || null,
                    tabindex: scope.tabindex || attrs.tabindex || null

                }).then(function (widgetId) {
                    // The widget has been created
                ...
```

The possible types can be found at the reCaptcha documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param . There seem to be two attributes related to the rendering:

```
+------------+-------+----------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
| data-theme | theme | dark light     | light  | Optional. The color theme of the widget. |
| data-type  | type  | audio image    | image  | Optional. The type of CAPTCHA to serve.  |
| data-size  | size  | compact normal | normal | Optional. The size of the widget.        |
+------------+-------+----------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

So it seems you have options for theme, type and size, but are not able to switch to the old reCAPTCHA. You could try to switch to the old version of reCAPTCHA and check if it is compatible with the chosen angular wrapper.